# How do I get a Xamarin ListView to automatically size its rows without resizing the screen?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, windows-8.1

I have a ListView in my Xamarin app, defined like so:

```
        listView = new ListView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            RowHeight = -1,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                var nameLabel = new Label
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start
                };
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "DisplayName");

                var statusLabel = new Label 
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End
                };
                statusLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Status");

                var grid = new Grid
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                    RowDefinitions = {
                        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
                    },
                    ColumnDefinitions = {
                        new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                        new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
                    }
                };

                grid.Children.Add(nameLabel, 0, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(statusLabel, 1, 0);

                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = grid
                };
            })
        };
```

When I first set its `ItemsSource` property, the rows are clipped like so:

[image: ListView with clipped rows]

If I resize the screen, they get resized to the correct size:

[image: ListView with resized rows]

If I change the `ItemsSource` again, they go back to being clipped.  Calling `UpdateChildrenLayout` or `ForceLayout` has no effect.

How do I get the ListView to size its rows correctly, without having to ask the user to resize their window? That's going to be a tough ask on mobile!

Answer (score 8):

If the ListView is a full screen one then set `VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand`. 
Do not set the `RowHeight` statically. Since you have `HasUnevenRows=true` it would size different rows differently based on the size of the content inside it. 
Also provide the `VerticalOptions` for the controls inside the ItemTemplate of listview, so that they will be sized properly.